# Python how to convert a list data to pandas keeping the property of the column (ive a dict in the list, which i want to retain)?

Tags: python, json, pandas, list

Below is the data which I've with me:

```py
data_list=[{'Col1': '24', 'Col2': '8'}, {'Col1': '25', 'Col2': '9'}]
```

data type for the above is `list`.

I need this data be converted this to the below format:

```py
Data_Field
{'Col1': '24', 'Col2': '8'}
{'Col1': '25', 'Col2': '9'}
```

How to get this done ?
I tried converting to pandas back and forth, which didnt work.

PS: I need this to be loaded to snowflake and this data is just one column in the table.

Regards,
Bobby

```py
data_list=[{'Col1': '24', 'Col2': '8'}, {'Col1': '25', 'Col2': '9'}]
```

I need this data be converted this to the below format:

```py
Data_Field
{'Col1': '24', 'Col2': '8'}
{'Col1': '25', 'Col2': '9'}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me working pass list to `Series` if working with dictionary:

```
data_list=[{'Col1': '24', 'Col2': '8'}, {'Col1': '25', 'Col2': '9'}]

s = pd.Series(data_list)
print (s)
0    {'Col1': '24', 'Col2': '8'}
1    {'Col1': '25', 'Col2': '9'}
dtype: object
```

Or to `Dataframe`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data_Field': data_list})
print (df)
                    Data_Field
0  {'Col1': '24', 'Col2': '8'}
1  {'Col1': '25', 'Col2': '9'}
```

If working with `json`, first use `json.loads` for `list of dictionaries`:

```
import json

#sample of json
j = json.dumps([{'Col1': '24', 'Col2': '8'}, {'Col1': '25', 'Col2': '9'}])

s = pd.Series(json.loads(j))
print (s)

0    {'Col1': '24', 'Col2': '8'}
1    {'Col1': '25', 'Col2': '9'}
dtype: object

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data_Field': json.loads(j)})
print (df)
                    Data_Field
0  {'Col1': '24', 'Col2': '8'}
1  {'Col1': '25', 'Col2': '9'}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked well for me, I used option 2.  sorry for the delay in responding.